# urinate and pass the bowels

Tags: word-request

What  is the formal word for urinating and passing the bowels? If we say 'He went to restroom' it isn't much clear, still. Or if we say, 'He went due to call of nature' it sounds humorous.

Comment: In what context or type of writing do you intend to use this?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a single **formal** word that takes in both **urinating** and **defecating**.

However, there are numerous ways of referring to both these actions.

The expression **to relieve oneself** serves on most occasions and can refer to either or both.

A host of other expressions, both formal and informal, can be found by clicking on the links below.

Although people visit restrooms (powder rooms, washrooms, lavatories, loos etc) for several reasons, it's seldom necessary to spell these out.

**They've gone to the washroom** says as much as is necessary unless there's a specific reason to refer to some unfortunate person's problems, such as those with constipation or diarrhea.

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/defecation
https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/urinate

Answer (score 1):

[*Elimination*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elimination) is the single word that encompasses both biological processes, but is much more apt to be used in a medical context, rather than in a colloquial one.